# Playing audio while applying video filter in GPUImage

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, gpuimage

I've googled this question but did not find any solution.

So, my problem is,
I'm applying video filter using `GPUImage` to a video file. At same time, sound of that video is not playing. I know that sound playing is not supported in `GPUImage` while applying filters.

So, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve sound playing by adding support for `AVPlayer` like this.

1. In `GPUImageMovie.h`,

   `@property(readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL playSound;`
2. In `GPUImageMovie.m`, update `@interface GPUImageMovie ()` like this.

   ```
   @interface GPUImageMovie() <AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate> 
   {
       // Add this
       BOOL hasAudioTrack;

       .........
       ........

      // Add all below three lines
      AVPlayer *theAudioPlayer;
      CFAbsoluteTime startActualFrameTime;
      CGFloat currentVideoTime;
   }
   ```
3. After that, in `-(void)startProcessing` method, add following lines.

   ```
   - (void)startProcessing
   {
      // Add this
      currentVideoTime = 0.0f;

      .....
      .....

      // Add this
      if (self.playSound)
      {
          [self setupSound];
      }

      GPUImageMovie __block *blockSelf = self;

      [inputAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler: ^{
       runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue(^{

               .........
               .........

               // Add this
               startActualFrameTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - currentVideoTime;

               .......
               .......
           });
      }];
   }
   ```
4. Again, In `-(AVAssetReader*)createAssetReader` update it,

   ```
   - (AVAssetReader*)createAssetReader
   {
       .......
       .......  
       BOOL shouldRecordAudioTrack = (([audioTracks count] > 0) &&  (self.audioEncodingTarget != nil));

       // Add this
       hasAudioTrack = ([audioTracks count] > 0);

       .........
   }
   ```
5. In `- (void)processAsset`,

   ```
   - (void)processAsset
   {

      .......
      .......

      if ([reader startReading] == NO)
      {
         NSLog(@"Error reading from file at URL: %@", self.url);
         return;
      }

      // Add this
      if (self.playSound && hasAudioTrack)
      {
         [theAudioPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
         [theAudioPlayer play];
      }

      .........
      .........
   }
   ```
6. In `-(void)endProcessing`,

   ```
   - (void)endProcessing
   {
      .........
      .........

      if (self.playerItem && (displayLink != nil))
      {
         [displayLink invalidate]; // remove from all run loops
         displayLink = nil;
      } 

      // Add this
      if (theAudioPlayer != nil)
      {
         [theAudioPlayer pause];
         [theAudioPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
      }

      .........
      .........
   }
   ```
7. Add new method `-(void)setupSound` at last,

   ```
   // Add this
   - (void)setupSound
   {
      if (theAudioPlayer != nil)
      {
          [theAudioPlayer pause];
          [theAudioPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
          theAudioPlayer = nil;
      }

      theAudioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:self.url];
   }
   ```
8. At last, when you create your `GPUImageMovie` object, don't forget to set `playSound` flag to `YES.`

   Like this : `movieFile.playSound = YES;`

   Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, video is not synced with audio in this solution. For 1min video audio finishes playing about 2-3s earlier than video.

Comment: @AntonKashpor, you've to edit pod to do changes in the pod file.

Comment: Any fix of issue with sound sync?

Answer (score 0):

how to pause the audio during filter applied by **GPUImage**?

Like we can pause the video writing by `movieWriter.paused = YES;` when I pause the movie writing, I need to Pause audio also.

Comment: You can pause audio by `[theAudioPlayer pause]` code.